# Consuming web service results in “Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter”

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, curl, fiddler

I need to consume web services on this .NET site:

https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223third_17/webservices/ItfResidentData.asmx

For preliminary consumption I use either Fiddler or curl.  Both give the same error:

```
<faultstring>Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.</faultstring>
```

My curl command:

curl -d @GetVersionNumber.xml https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223third_17/webservices/ItfResidentData.asmx

Please see file GetVersionNumber.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <GetVersionNumber xmlns="http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Adding SOAP-ENV:Header as element in soap:Envelope does not help

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header Content-Type="text/xml" Host="www.iyardiasp.com" SOAPAction="http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber"/>
```

Adding the Soap Action as a header does not help.

In this case the curl command is:

curl  -H "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber" -d @GetVersionNumber.xml "https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223third_17/webservices/itfapplicantscreening.asmx"

And the response is:

```
<faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber.</faultstring>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to supply the [`SOAPAction` as a HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528), not a SOAP header. Here is how a complete request might look like when performed with SoapUI (notice the forth row):

```
POST /8223third_17/webservices/ItfResidentData.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: www.iyardiasp.com
Content-Length: 260

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:itf="http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <itf:GetVersionNumber/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For `curl` you might use the [`-H`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) parameter to send the `SOAPAction` header but I suggest you [use SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) for your preliminary consumption (it includes the `SOAPAction` header by default and beats the console any day).

If you do need to use `curl`, try something like this (all must be on one line; separated for readability):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" 
     -H "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber\"" 
     -d @GetVersionNumber.xml 
     https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223third_17/webservices/ItfResidentData.asmx
```

with this in the `GetVersionNumber.xml` file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:itf="http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <itf:GetVersionNumber/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Bogdan, please see my addition to the request, thanks

Comment: Bogdan I checked from Fiddler with your headers - works fine, thanks. From curl it is not working yet

Comment: Bogdan, I tried several variants: for example:curl  -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfResidentData/GetVersionNumber"; Host: www.iyardiasp.com" -d @GetVersionNumber.xml "https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223third_17/webservices/itfapplicantscreening.asmx".  It is the same result

Answer (score 1):

Probably noone is using asmx files anymore - but I am :), and just came across the issue.   The general problem is that .net has no indication that this is a WebMethod that handles, among other things, soap requests.

The other answers may be valid in their own way, but for the super simple case, making sure your method is decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute solved my problem.

```
[WebMethod]
public string test() { return "Hello World"];
```

The attribute is probably also responsible for wrapping your response in a soap wrapper.

Ahh, Microsoft.  So much automatic, but even more learning curve.